# Mounting a drive using sshfs

Tags: mount, sshfs

I am trying mount a remote drive using sshfs on ubuntu 12.04.

I follow the steps here:
http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-mount-remote-directory-over-ssh-on-linux.html

But after I did `sshfs` successfully, I did `ls`,

I get:

```
ls: cannot access sshdrive: Permission denied
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Oct 30 09:10 ./
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Apr 23  2013 ../
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? sshdrive/
```

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

After doing usermod, make sure that group membership change takes effect.

For that, you can run:

`$ exec su -l $USER`

Alternatively, you can log out and log back in.

Comment: It does not work. When I do 'exec su -l $USER', my terminal just kills itself. When I open a new terminal, I still get Permission denied'

Comment: Relogging in does not help either?